# Unicycling for over 60s

Tags: safety, fitness, skills, unicycle

Are you an over-60 unicyclist with insights you would like to share, about anything from getting started to getting off?

Comment: I am approaching 70, and enjoy unicycling very much.  I would like to share my experiences and hear from others.

Comment: Voting to close as it is very broad for the Q&A format.

Comment: Sorry you feel that way Batman; please reconsider. Let's have a little fun!

Comment: sorry @user2332668 but I agree with Batman. You're trying to start a debate here and that's not a good fit for for this particular site.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. This site is not a typical forum. Like all Stack Exchange sites, we operate on a Q&A format. We are looking for questions with specific answers [rather than open-ended discussions](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Once you have asked and answered a few questions, you'll have earned enough [reputation](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to participate in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome), where this kind of discussion would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of insights about getting started, that might be helpful. 
1.  Use walking sticks for a few weeks or months - you will know when to throw them away.
2.  Get good body armour - I particularly recommend Kris Holme gloves.  You will also need knee and elbow pads, and a good helmet.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need inspiration to get started.  Check out this Kris Home video: